# Dart type checking with type reference as variable

Tags: dart, typechecking

I am trying to type check in Dart with a Type reference stored as a variable.
Something like this:

```
    class Thingamajig {}
    
    bool method(dynamic object) {
      var Type type = Thingamajig;
      if (object is type) { //gives error: type_test_with_non_type
        doSomething();
      }
    }
```

My use case requires the sub-type checking functionality of `is`, so `runtimeType` will not suffice. How can I accomplish this and eliminate the error?

EDIT:
My true intent was to have the type as an instance variable on a Finder class implementation for a Flutter widget test. I can solve this problem with something like this:

```dart
if (type == MyClass && object is MyClass)
if (type == MyOtherClass && object is MyOtherClass)
```

or

```dart
switch (type) {
    case MyClass:
        if (object is MyClass) //do stuff
        break;
    case MyOtherClass:
        if (object is MyOtherClass) // do other stuff
        break;
}
```

but I was hoping for a cleaner option.

Comment: A cleaner option is to use a type variable on the class instead of an instance variable holding a `Type` object. Using a `Type` object is almost always the wrong design since you can't do anything useful with a `Type` object other than compare it for equality and using `dart:mirrors`. If you need to *change* the instance variable value, I'd create an abstraction, like `class MyType<T> {  bool isInstance(Object o) => o is T; bool operator >=(MyType other) => other is MyType<T>; }`, and then pass that around instead of a `Type` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply pass the type literal into the `is` expression, and it will work:

```
var type = MyCustomClass;
if (object is type) ...  // "type" is not a type
if (object is MyCustomClass)  // works fine, including subtypes
```

If you can't do that (maybe you want to pass in the type as a parameter), you can instead use a type parameter:

```
bool checkType<T>(dynamic object) {
  if (object is T) ...  // works fine
}
```

However if you want your types to be dynamic at runtime, you're slightly out of luck. If this is what you want, perhaps some context on why you want that would help inform a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've edited the question with some additional context. Either of these methods would work for this case. I was hoping there would be a slightly cleaner option.